# Sunset Tunnel - Event Abandoned

Tags: need-for-speed-rivals

When playing the Sunset Tunnel race, I invariably get booted from the race with an "Event Abandoned" message in the middle of my screen, despite the fact that I am usually in the middle of the pack at this point. This always happens on the serpentine stretch of road close to the start of the race. This is the only event that seems to do this. How can I avoid this bug?

Answer (score 1):

This bug is caused by launching the game in 60FPS mode. To avoid it, you need to either delete `-GameTime.MaxSimFps 60 -GameTime.ForceSimRate 60.0` from the game shortcut's target property or launch the game .exe directly from its install directory.

Answer (score 0):

I tried several alternatives, one did not work.

One working theory !!

Create shortcut Nfs icon and editing one section

Literally Copy and paste to the **Target:**
*"C:\Program Files (x86)\Need for Speed Rivals\NFS14.exe" -GameTime.MaxSimFps 35-GameTime.ForceSimRate 30*

This command is results in an appropriate FPS, not slow and not too fast.
And good news, no more "Event Abandoned"

Greeting
from Hungary :)